# colorbox iframe not working with jquery 1.11

Tags: jquery, colorbox

When I use jquery-1.11.0.min.js, colorbox does not load videos correctly. The colorbox div displays, but no YouTube video is loaded.  See [OADG Dutt Roth video](http://www.ottawadressage.ca/duttroth/).  When I use a jquery-1.7.1, the videos load correctly.  See [OADG Horse video](http://www.ottawadressage.ca/horses/#willy).  Can someone identify a solution which works with 1.11.0 please?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery.colorbox-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    /*<![CDATA[*/               
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.youtube').colorbox({iframe: true, width: 853, height: 480, href:function(){
    var videoId = new RegExp('[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)').exec(this.href);
    if (videoId && videoId[1]) {
        return 'http://youtube.com/embed/'+videoId[1]+'?rel=0&wmode=transparent';
    }
}});        
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
<div>
    <p><a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Z_nAZI5dfx0?rel=0" title="Susanne Dutt-Roth Riding D2 March, 2012"><img src="S_DuttRothFeb2012.jpg" title="Susanne Dutt-Roth Riding D2 March, 2012" alt="Susanne Dutt-Roth Riding D2 March, 2012"/></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I found the issue. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery colorbox is compatible only with jquery 1.3+. You'd have to refer an update version of jquery in your code.

"Compatible with: jQuery 1.3.2+"
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Your this link (http://www.ottawadressage.ca/duttroth/) has more than one jQuery files included. Please remove the older versions referred in the `<head>` section.

Comment: I was using jquery 1.11.0, 1.7-1 is commented out. If I use 1.11.0 or 1.9.0 alone, the YouTube video opens on top of the webpage, as colorbox.js refers to $.browser which is deprecated.  If I use 1.11.0 with the migrate-1.2.1, the colorbox opens, but no video is downloaded into the box. There is no evidence of getting the YouTube video via the link. It looks like something changed after 1.7.1 where colorbox with video does not work. As long as only images are referenced by colorbox, it works in 1.11.0.